# Not able to get data when form is submitted using phpmailer and later forwared

Tags: forms, gmail, phpmailer

Simple PHP script to capture user form input and send me email.

Empty form gets submitted using phpmailer script i.e. Receiving email without user filled data. There is no SMTP error, Page get submitted and redirected to new Page. Request to please help. Sometimes email received also form has user filled data also, not sure why ?

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require './PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';



try {
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
     $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  
    $mail->Username = "XXXXX@gmail.com";  
    $mail->Password = "XXXXX";  
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  
    $mail->Port = 587;  



    $mail->setFrom('XXXXX@gmail.com', 'Mr Singh');
    $mail->addReplyTo('XXXXX@gmail.com', 'Mr Singh');
    $mail->addAddress('XXXXX@gmail.com', 'Mr Singh');



    $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Exceptions test';
$mail->isHTML(false);


        $mail->Body = <<<EOT
Email: {$_POST['name']}
Email: {$_POST['email']}
Mobile: {$_POST['mobile']}
EOT;

    $mail->send();
    header("Refresh:1; contact.html");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();  
} catch (\Exception $e) { //The leading slash means the Global PHP Exception class will be caught
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this script is ever run *at all*, it will send an email, regardless of whether any data was submitted or not. Wrap it in a condition that only sends a message if data has been submitted, something like:

```
if (isset(_POST['email'])) {
   try {
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
...
```

You can be more thorough about this check, for example validate that a valid email address was submitted, that the other fields contain what you expect, and so on, but you should get the general idea.

Comment: Thanks, Kept only if statement and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Kept only if statement and its working now. Able to use use Gmail SMTP services. For Gmail had to enable less secure app in Gmail and changed password once.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require './PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{  

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

    //Set the hostname of the mail server
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // Which SMTP server to use.
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Whether you need to login. This is almost always required.
    $mail->Username = "XXXXX@gmail.com"; // Your Gmail address.
    $mail->Password = "XXXXX"; // Your Gmail login password or App Specific Password.
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Which security method to use. TLS is most secure.
    $mail->Port = 587; // Which port to use, 587 is the default port for TLS security.


    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail->setFrom('XXXXXgmail.com', 'Mr Singh');
    //Set an alternative reply-to address
    $mail->addReplyTo('XXXXX@gmail.com', 'Mr Singh');
    //Set who the message is to be sent to
    $mail->addAddress('YYYYY@gmail.com', 'Mr Singh');


    $mail->Subject = 'Customer Enquiry Form';


    $mail->isHTML(false);


        $mail->Body = <<<EOT
        Email: {$_POST['name']}
        Email: {$_POST['email']}
        Mobile: {$_POST['mobile']}

EOT;

        $mail->send();
        header("Refresh:1; contact.html");


}  else {
    echo "Your form is not submitted yet please call for booking";
}
?>
```

HTML Code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="submit" action="PHPMailer.php" method="post">
.......    ** HTML CODE of Form  .......
<input value="submit" name="submit" type="submit">
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped, but please don't post comments and additional code as answers - edit your question instead.